# Is every compact space 1st countable?

Tags: general-topology

I'm tasked with proving or disproving: every compact space must satisfy the first axiom of countability. The hint I am given is: think of the product space given by uncountably many copies of the compact space $[0,1]$. I know from Tychonoff's theorem that $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ is compact. From analysis I know that the topology for $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ is not metrizable since this space is not finite-dimensional. The hint is making me think that not every compact space satisfies the first axiom of countability. Not sure where to go from here. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what basic open sets in $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ look like?  Can you conclude something about a countable intersection of open neighborhoods of a point?

Comment: Another example would be the cofinite topology on an uncountable set.

Comment: @BrianMoehring not at all. Epsilon balls seem gone since the space isn't metrizable.

Comment: If you are familiar with ordinal numbers and their topology, $\omega_1 + 1$ is compact, but not first countable.

Comment: What does finite dimensionality have to do with metrizability?

Comment: You may want to look at [how we define the product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition) then.

Comment: @ronno if we have a metric then we have an idea of openness through balls of radius defined by the metric.

Comment: But what does that have to do with finite dimensionality? For example $\ell_p$, the set of sequences $(x_n)$ with $\sum |x_n|^p < \infty$ is a metric space but is also infinite dimensional under all applicable definitions of dimension that I can think of.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'm familiar with the definition but in this uncountable scenario it's a little hard to wrap my head around. I know the base of the topology comes from these open sets of [0,1] and we're taking an uncountable product of them. There's a finite number of these that don't equal [0,1] but the rest do equal [0,1]. I'm sure that's important but I'm not seeing it yet. I guess a basic open set in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ would be an arbitrary union of basis elements. Because our basis elements are an uncountable product, then it can't be 1st countable because good luck trying to count

Comment: @BrianMoehring something uncountable.

Comment: @ronno that's true. We do have a norm in that space so our metric is induced by the norm, so that helps. I can't begin to think of a norm for this space though.

Comment: $[0, 1]^\mathbb{R}$ is in fact not metrizable, but I just don't see the relevance of it being infinite dimensional. It is not obvious to me what definition of dimension applies to $[0, 1]^\mathbb{R}$ either.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see an argument I tried to make a couple of weeks ago that used this idea but maybe the execution is wrong because now that I'm looking at it it's not so clear. I assume $\mathbb{R}$ with the co-finite topology is 1st countable, then I show it's not. I never mentioned compactness which confuses me.

Comment: @ronno what makes this problem so hard for me is the fact that $[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ is not metrizable. I know the space is compact by Tychonoff's theorem. So if I have an open cover, then any point in the space will be in at least one of the open sets that make up my finite subcover. So I have that open set as a neighborhood and I know open sets can be constructed by unions of basis elements. I just can't think of a countable local basis that will have an element that I can sandwich in between my point and some arbitrary neighborhood of the point.

Comment: @Chenoeh I don’t understand. Why would you need to mention compactness when showing it’s not first countable? The point is that you can show that it is compact and also show that it is not first countable, so it’s a counterexample, different from the one in the hint.

Comment: Again, none of this has anything to do with (in)finite dimensionality. It's reasonable that you can't find a countable local basis because there isn't one.

Comment: @Chenoeh regarding your latest comment, why are you trying to find a countable local base when the problem is to show that there isn’t one?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen because $\mathbb{R}$ is compact with the co-finite topology, my bad. I get it now. That slipped my mind

Comment: @ronno when I first saw this question I was leaning towards it actually being true. The hint provided made me think it wasn't but I had not convinced myself why at that point. While I appreciate a lot of the comments being about ordinal numbers and giving examples with those, I have very little knowledge of them so those examples don't resonate with me personally. I'll write up the proof I am thinking of and submit to this thread. Now knowing that this is indeed not true I think will help me understand the ordinal examples better.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen tried to tag you in my last comment but I guess you can only tag one user at a time

Comment: @Chenoeh your answer looks right to me

Answer (score 1):

While (as Ulli's comment says) $\omega_1+1$ is itself a compact space that is not first-countable, it is embeddable in $[0,1]^{\mathbb R}$ since it is Tychonoff and has weight $\le c$ (the open intervals form a base). So having a subspace not first-countable, $[0,1]^{\mathbb R}$ cannot be first-countable.

The following proof follows Engelking's *General Topology*.

Let $\omega_1$ be the smallest uncountable ordinal. Let the topology on $\omega_1+1$ be generated by the base consisting of intervals
$$[0,\alpha),\;(\alpha,\beta),\;(\alpha,\omega_1]$$
where $\alpha<\beta\le\omega_1$.

Lemma. Every base of neighborhoods of $\omega_1\in\omega_1+1$ is uncountable. So $\omega_1+1$ is not first-countable.

Proof. Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a base of neighbourhoods of $\omega_1$. For each $i$ choose an interval $(\alpha_i,\omega_1]\subseteq U_i$. By the definition of a base of neighbourhoods every interval of the form $(\alpha,\omega_1]$ should contain some $(\alpha_i,\omega_1]$. It can be verified that the union of the countable sets $[0,\alpha_i]$ is equal to the whole $\omega_1$, which is uncountable. This shows that $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an uncountable family.

Lemma. $\omega_1+1$ is a compact Hausdorff space (hence Tychonoff) and has weight $\le c$.

Proof. The family of open intervals has cardinality $\le\omega_1^2\le c^2=c$. So the weight of $\omega_1+1$ is $\le c$. If $\alpha<\beta$ are distinct ordinals in $\omega_1+1$, then $\alpha+1\le\beta$. So $[0,\alpha+1)$ and $(\alpha+1,\omega_1]$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $\alpha,\beta$. So $\omega_1+1$ is Hausdorff.

It remains to show that $\omega_1+1$ is compact. Let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $\omega_1+1$. If $\alpha\in\omega_1+1$ and $[0,\beta]$ is covered by finitely many members of $\mathcal U$ for every $\beta<\alpha$, then $[0,\alpha]$ is covered by some $U\in\mathcal U$ for which $\alpha\in(\beta,\gamma)\subseteq U$ for some $\beta<\alpha<\gamma\le\omega_1+1$ and finitely many members of $\mathcal U$ that covers $[0,\beta]$. By transfinite induction, every $[0,\alpha]\subseteq\omega_1+1$ is covered by a finite subfamily of $\mathcal U$, and in particular so is $\omega_1+1=[0,\omega_1]$.

Lemma. A Tychonoff space $X$ of weight $\le c$ is embeddable in $[0,1]^c$.

Proof. Since $X$ is Tychonoff, the family of preimages $f^{-1}((0,1])$ of continuous maps $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ is a base. This base has a subfamily $\{f_i^{-1}((0,1])\}_{i\in I}$ with $|I|\le c$ that is still a base of $X$. Let the map $$f\colon X\to[0,1]^I$$ defined by
$$f(x)=(f_i(x))_{i\in I}.$$
We shall show that $f$ is an embedding. The map $f$ is continuous because each $f_i$ is. It is easily verified that $f$ is injective using the fact that $\{f_i^{-1}((0,1])\}_{i\in I}$ is a base and $X$ is a T1 space. It remains to verify that the image $f(U)$ of an open subset $U\subseteq X$ is open in the range $f(X)$. That is, for each $x\in U$ we need to find an open subset $V\subseteq[0,1]^I$ such that
$$f(x)\in V\cap f(X)\subseteq f(U).$$
Let us take $i_0\in I$ such that
$$ x\in f_{i_0}^{-1}((0,1])\subseteq U.$$
Then the proof is complete by taking $V=p_{i_0}^{-1}((0,1])$ and noting that $[0,1]^I$ is embeddable in $[0,1]^c$.

Theorem. $[0,1]^c$ is not first-countable.

Proof. By the last two lemmas $\omega_1+1$ is isomorphic to a subset of $[0,1]^c$. By the first lemma $\omega_1+1$ is not first-countable. So neither is $[0,1]^c$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Brian Moehring in the comments, it suffices to show that the intersection of any countable collection of open neighborhoods of a point is not the singleton containing that point (why?). We can assume that the open sets are all basic, i.e. that they are products of intervals with all but finitely many of the intervals being $[0,1]$.

Since there are uncountably many indices and countably many open sets, by the pigeonhole principle, there is some index such that each of the open sets’ projection onto that index is $[0,1].$ Therefore, since the intersection is nonempty, the projection of the intersection onto this index is $[0,1]$, and this implies that there are at least as many points in the intersection as there are points in $[0,1]$, so the intersection is not a singleton.

As I suggested in the comments, similar logic (though perhaps a little simpler) can show that an uncountable set with the cofinite topology is not first countable. And since the cofinite topology is compact, this also serves as a counterexample to the main question.

As suggested by Ulli, the ordinal $\omega_1+1$ is also a counterexample, perhaps the most transparent of the three, provided you are familiar with ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone who posted on this thread. I am going to give a counterexample in two steps, I hope to summarize and use a little of what everyone said.

Step 1: Claim: all non-empty (to avoid the trivial case) sets given the co-finite topology are compact.

Proof: Let X be a non-empty set equipped with the co-finite topology. Let O be an open cover of X. Pick $O_{j} \in O$. Then $X \setminus O_{j} = \{x_{1}, x_{2},..., x_{n}\}$. $\forall i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ let $O_{i} \in O$ such that $x_{i} \in O_{i}$. Then $\{O_{j}, O_{1}, O_{2},..., O_{n}\}$ is a finite subcover of X. So X with the co-finite topology is compact.

Step 2: Claim: $\mathbb{R}$ with the co-finite topology is not 1st countable.

Proof: We know $\mathbb{R}$ with the co-finite topology is compact. For the sake of contradiction assume that this topological space is 1st countable. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and let V be a countable local basis of open neighborhoods of x. $\forall V_n \in V$  $\exists$ a finite set f_{n} such that $f_{n} = \mathbb{R} \setminus V_{n}$. Let $F=\{x\} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}$. So F is countable. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, $\exists y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus F$. Let $U = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{y\}$. Since $\{y\}$ is finite, then U is an open set containing x. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $y \notin f_{n}$, so $y \in V_{n}$ but $y \notin U$. Thus $y \in V_{n} \setminus U$, hence $V_{n} \not\subset U$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. So we get V is NOT a countable local basis of x, hence a contradiction.